# Change datePicker month format in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, datepicker, format

I have a DatePicker in my application and I want to display the date in this format : 11/26/2019
So I change the `Format` property as follow :

```
myDatePicker.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"
myDatePicker.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

But the display date got this format : 
November 26 2019

May I have to do other things for this ?

Comment: Your code works fine on my side .Which platform did you test ? And could you provide the version of your device?

Comment: I'm on UWP. Exactly, I want the format IN my date picker like 11 26 2019. So it's the format the month I wan't to change, but it still get the month name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an existing issue of Xamarin.forms for UWP .As workaround, you can reset the format of **DatePicker** by using **Custom Renderer** .

#### in UWP project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using xxx.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms;
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker),typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace xxx.UWP
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer:DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.MonthFormat = "{month.integer}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will post the issue on github immediately ,and will reply you if has any update.

Comment: Morehover, it's the same way if I want to center the text in the date picker ?